# How can I extract specific part of a file?

Tags: text-processing

I have multiple files containing several different lines. Among the lines, I am interested only in the ones starting with a specific pattern, such as:

```
USER1    Info> :FERRARI:RED,:LAMBORGHINI:ORANGE,:MASERATI:BLUE,...
```

In this example 
(with spaces as indicated).

From these lines I only need the car's make info (without the colours) so the output should look like this:

```
FERRARI, LAMBORGHINI and MASERATI
```

The car's make are always different in each file. In the example I put 3 car's make, but in each file they could be less or more. 
Is there an easy way to do this in bash or python?
Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211753/5217119
Hints: you need to extract columns $2,$4,$6

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually, columns may be more than 3. I put 3 in the question only as an example, but depending on the file, they could be less or more, and I can't know how many of them are in each file before.

Comment: Edited. My apologize for not being clear enough. I hope now it is clearer.

Comment: Note that `AA,` and `BB,` are also *"words which is between the two colons"*. What specific criteria distinguish the parts you want to retain from these?

Comment: the comma is the separator. I will try to edit the question with a more specific example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract every word (not contains comma) which is between the two colons

```
grep -oHnE ":[^,]*:" files* | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {x=$1$2; a[x]=a[x]","$4} END{for(x in a) print a[x]}' | sed 's/^,//'
```

Assuming we have file car_info.txt

```
cat car_info.txt
USER1    Info> :FERRARI:RED,:LAMBORGHINI:ORANGE,:MASERATI:BLUE
USER1    Info> :FERRARI:RED,:LAMBORGHINI:ORANGE
USER1    Info> :FERRARI:RED,:LAMBORGHINI:ORANGE,:MASERATI:BLUE


grep -oHnE ":[^,]*:" car_info.txt 
car_info.txt:1::FERRARI:
car_info.txt:1::LAMBORGHINI:
car_info.txt:1::MASERATI:
car_info.txt:2::FERRARI:
car_info.txt:2::LAMBORGHINI:
car_info.txt:3::FERRARI:
car_info.txt:3::LAMBORGHINI:
car_info.txt:3::MASERATI:
```

`grep`

- `-o` prints only the matched parts of a matching line
- `-H` prints filenames
- `-n` prints line numbers
- `-E` to support extended-regex

Now the strategy is to make the lines with same `filename:line` to be shown in one line

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {x=$1$2;a[x]=a[x]","$4} END{for(x in a) print a[x]}'
```

- `BEGIN{FS=":"}` setting the field separator to `:`
- `x=$1$2` put `filename` and `line` in `x`
- create a key-value `a` with key=`x` and adding the 4th field to it's value in each line with same `x`
- `for(x in a) print a[x]` print the values of the key-value `a`

`sed 's/^,//'` is for removing `,` from the begining of lines

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but it won't recognize the first part of the line:
*** Unbound variable: USER
(You're accessing an undefined variable or function `USER')

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Actually, I tried it now but the only thing I got are the commas. I copied your script as it is and changed "files*" with the file name.
I am really new to this things, so I apologize if I am doing some very basic error.

Comment: the file I am using to try your script is car_info.txt

Comment: well.. this quite did the job. The output is a list of the words in the file between the two colons. Now the only thing I need to do is to select only the lines starting with "USER1    Info> "

Comment: @ginopino I found the problem, please have a look at the answer

Comment: this worked! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @ginopino I added some details to make it more clear and did some small modifications.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Now it is much more clear, even for a noob like me :)

Answer (score 0):

`awk -F':' /^USER1.\*Info/' {print $2" "$4" "$6}' < infile`